# Programmatically click the Done button on a Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I programmatically click the Done button on the Contextual Action Bar? Or more specifically, what is the `id` for this button? If I know that much, I can use Robotium to click on the view.

**Update:**

`hierarchyviewer` shows an attribute `mId` with value `NO_ID`, so now I need help with my original question. Does anyone have any other ideas of how to do this? In particular, I need to click the Done button during a test.

Comment: Looks like it has `NO_ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or more specifically, what is the id for this button?

The ID you're looking for is [`action_mode_close_button`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_mode_close_item.xml#L18).

> How can I programmatically click the Done button on the Contextual
>   Action Bar?

You can call [`View.performClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29). You'll need to give the `View` a moment to be laid out so that it won't return `null` though. A simple solution to that would be to post a `Runnable` using your `ListView` or whatever you're using to start the `ActionMode`. Here's an example:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mList.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    findViewById(android.R.id.action_mode_close_button).performClick();
                }
            }, 1000);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Or I could use `android.R.id.action_mode_close_button` which seems preferrable to `getIdentifier()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yep, didn't realize the id was public. Was this not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Just in case someone else has the same trouble that I had getting access to `android.R.id.action_mode_close_button`: You need to import the  [v7 appcompat library including its resources](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) as the id is not part of the standard 'android.R.id' class.

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky and I don't like using it but it works.

```
int doneButtonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");
View doneButton = getActivity().findViewById(doneButtonId);

if(doneButton != null && doneButton.isClickable(){
doneButton.performClick();
}
```

I think the .isClickable() is probably unnecessary but I leave it in just in case.

Comment: This seems to repeat the information given in the other answer. (Or rather a previous version of said answer.)